# Windows Server 2003 File Share Disconnect

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

I have a Windows 2003 Standard Edition Server with three file shares.

At random times during the day the shared network drives stop responding and the users complain of programs hanging that have files open on these shares.

The server doesn't actually close the files open on the shared drive, but it does seem to lock them out for a few seconds before becoming responsive again and letting users access the files.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

When this is occurring, is the server also inaccessible over the network? Also, what about outgoing network access from the server itself?

If overall incoming and outgoing network access is disrupted during these events, then you might try hard coding the network line settings on either the server and/or switch. "Auto-detect" mismatches/incompatibilities can exhibit similar random conditions.